# "Child of" bone constraint on multiple bones, rotation issue

Tags: constraints

I am looking for a way to get multiples bones to parent a control bone in a particular way. At the front of my cat model I have a bone I call "direction driver." In the cat skeleton I have some bones with a "child of" constraint, the target being the "driver" bone. When I rotate the "driver" I want each of these other bones to rotate the same, but in place. Currently, they all seem to be pivoting around the "driver bone" as if they constituted a single object. Pictures below. Can someone help me achieve my goal of getting them to copy rotation while staying in place? I cannot use the "copy rotation" constraint on them because they are already rotating in and of themselves, and I dont want to simply "replace" their rotation with the "drivers" I want an additive effect. Since I can get bones that have translational movement on the y axis (in and of themselves) to additionally parent y translational movement of the "driver bone" I am hoping that I can achieve the same thing with rotation. Thanks!
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can duplicate all your desired "Child " bones, and set a copy rot constraints on each of thoose duplicates, then make every original bone child of its duplicate, so that first you rotate the driver (and duplicate and its child rotate accordingly) then you can add its own rotation to every child.